# Submitting a single text input to mysql on a page with multiple text inputs

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

For my application, I have several hundred text inputs inside a table, each with their own submit buttons. Each text field needs to be able to be submitted to MySQL separately. How would I go about accomplishing this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".toggler").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.cat' + $(this).attr('data-prod-cat')).toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Price</td>
    <td>Destination</td>
    <td>Updated on</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>
      <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="1">+ On Store</button>
    </td>
    <td>22/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat1" style="display:none">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Amount:
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>100</td>
    <td>
      <button class="toggler" data-prod-cat="2">+ On Store</button>
    </td>
    <td>22/10</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="cat2" style="display:none">
    <td style="white-space: nowrap">Enter Amount:
      <input type="text" maxlength="4" name="quantity" class="input" />&nbsp;<a href="#" class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```html
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("site_url","id","password");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }

 

mysql_select_db("cis_id", $con);

 

$sql="INSERT INTO table (price)

VALUES

('$_POST[price]')";

 

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 record added";

 

mysql_close($con)

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to submit an input is to create a form but since in your case creating a form will be one hell of a work. so i would go with calling a ajax function and passing a value("quantity") to your page.

```
$('.submit').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var me = $(this);
   $.ajax({
      type:"post",     
      data: {price : me.closest('.input').val()},
      url: "link/to/your/mysql/function/"
   }).done(function(html){
      alert(success);
   });
 });
```

PHP

```
echo $_POST[price]; //should give you the price
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response, is there anything I need to do to my jquery/html/php to work with this function?

Comment: well make sure all of your submit button has a "submit class", the ajax `url` option should exactly point to your .php file where you can get your post values through `$_POST['price']` and do the needful there (saving it to mysql and so on), echo success at the end of the page if it is succesfully saved else echo error.

Answer (score 0):

Use an AJAX call submitting only the field you need. Like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: POST, url: http:/yourdomain.com/yourajaxpage.php
    data: { 
        fieldToSubmit: $('#field).val()
    }
}).done(function( res ) {
    // whatever you want to do on return;
});
```

on PHP the field on "data" will be available in $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Your sql is wrong in php, the query is taking brackets as a string. Use the code below in php file

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("site_url","id","password");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

  }



mysql_select_db("cis_id", $con);

 $var = $_POST[price];

$sql="INSERT INTO table (price)

VALUES

('$var')";



if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))

  {

  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());

  }

echo "1 record added";



mysql_close($con)

?>
```

Hope this helps you